# Anger threw an AirPod at my Touch Bar and now my AUX isn't working?

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

Thanks a lot in advance for anyone’s time and advice. Pretty sad here. I have a Macbook Pro 13-inch 2019. Today, after a very frustrating meeting I took my earbuds off in a frustrated manner and when I tossed one aside, it hit my Touch Bar and cracked it about half a centimeter on the left side near the thunderbolt ports. The touch bar immediately turned funky colours and went pixelated and now is mostly black except for the escape symbol (thank goodness) which is visible.

Now my AUX port isn’t working. Are they connected? How does a tiny crack on the left side of the Touch Bar near the thunderbolt ports made my AUX port (on the right side) stop working? If I take this to a repair shop, will replacing the AUX port and not the Touch Bar be doable and moderately simple or have I screwed myself? Kinda freaking out because I work online and need to use my headphones everyday.

I bought the laptop of the Apple refurbished site in July 2020. So I’m unsure where I stand with warranty and possible fixing. But I am in Colombia right now, where there is no Apple Store anyways :(

My friend suggested I get bluetooth headphones so I’ll probably do that immediately.

Looking for any suggestions or advice one might have. I remember a few years ago my AUX port on an iPhone 6 stopped working and someone recommended resetting something in settings and it actually worked?! Anyone heard of something similar working for Mac? I'd have no idea what to reset.

Comment: Have you checked in **System Preferences** > **Sound** > **Output** > **Output volume:** that the **[] Mute** _check box_ is not checked and or the _slider_ is not all the way to the _left_?

Comment: Buying from the Refurbished Apple site was not the problem. Perhaps an anger management course may help or have a foam brick to throw instead.